# How can you trigger a focus event on a text node using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an html text node (an `li` tag in this case) that I am trying to trigger focus on using jQuery:

```
$('#branch').focus();
```

Or even:

```
$('#branch').trigger('focus');
```

I have attached an event listener:

```
$('#branch').on('focus', function() { console.log('focused'); });
```

But the event listener isn't firing. What do I need to do to fire this event listener?

If I listen for a 'hocus' event, and fire that event instead, the listener does indeed fire:

[image: listener firing for hocus but not focus]

(I need this to unit test what happens when you focus on the node, I'm building an [accessible tree](http://www.oaa-accessibility.org/examplep/treeview1/))

Comment: `hocus pocus` and `abracadabra` magic events...must be ES7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As detailed by [Shane Tomlinson here](https://shanetomlinson.com/2014/test-element-focus-javascript/):

> Text nodes are considered to be inert, and therefore cannot be
>   "focused" [according to the w3c](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/editing.html#focus-management)

Firing jQuery's `.focus()` method on a text node basically just gets swallowed up.

Instead, you have to use vanilla JS (works in Chrome, haven't tested other browsers):

```
            $('#branch').on('focus', function () {
                console.log('jquery listened');
            });

            var branch = document.getElementById('branch');

            branch.addEventListener('focus', function() {
                console.log('js listened');
            });

            // $('#branch').focus(); // this doesn't work! Use JS below instead...

            var event = new Event('focus');

            branch.dispatchEvent(event);
```

[See jsbin of example](http://jsbin.com/nucayiqoqu/edit?js,console,output)